# How do I deal with the order of schemas and users in a SQL Server database project?

Tags: sql-server, database, dacpac

I have inherited a SQL Server database project. The database has a system login already created (`my_user`), and the project creates the database user for it:

```
IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = 'my_user')
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'my_user'))
    CREATE USER [my_user] 
    FOR LOGIN [my_user] 
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [my_schema];

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'my_user';

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::my_schema TO [my_user];
GO
```

This file was called via the post-deployment script, but I moved it to the pre-deployment script since I thought I needed this user earlier in the process.  There is also a build script that creates the schema named `my_schema`.  However, I'm running into a Catch-22 with the user and schema.  If I create the schema in a pre-deploy script, which is not built, then I get build errors from the build scripts that reference the schema.  If I create the user in the pre-deploy scripts, then references to the user in the build scripts return a build error.  What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: For the script in your question, obviously `my_schema` has to be created before you run that.   What is the script that gives you a problem if you create the schema before the user?

Comment: I have added a build script that just calls `CREATE SCHEMA [my_schema]` and I have tried the same script in my Pre-deploy scripts.    If I do that in the pre-deploy scripts, then the build scripts do not know that the schema is there, so the build fails.  If I create my user in the pre-deploy scripts, then the build scripts do not know it's there and fail to build.  If I create the user in the build scripts, that helps, but I'm using `CREATE USER [my_user] FOR LOGIN [my_login] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[my_schema]` and I get flagged fo an unresolved reference to `my_login` even though it's in the DB

Comment: In my past experience, we usually have the database, schema, and at least the app user's login created prior to using dacpacs.  Dacpacs were used for objects like tables, functions, stored procs, and maybe additional users (our app didn't need additional users in the db).

Comment: If the schema is already created, then how do I deal with build failures related to calls like this: `create view [my_schema].[my_table] as ...`?  I get SQL71501 errors telling me that there is an unresolved reference to the schema since I don't create the schema in the DB project.